# Call something based on UITableView rows selected, in an IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I just saw a post about selecting multiple UITableView rows and based on which row/rows are selected, something will happen when you press a button linked to an IBAction.

It's an interesting question and I've played around with it, but now I'm stuck  a bit.

As you can see I have a NSMutableArray called selectedIndexes, and the selected row/rows are shown in the console using a NSLog. This works fine:

```
- (IBAction)doSomethingWithSelectedRows:(id)sender {

for (NSNumber *data in self.selectedIndexes) {
    NSLog(@"Row %ld is selected.", (long)[data integerValue] +1);
}

if (WHAT SHOULD BE PUT HERE?) {      
}
//Do whatever you want here.
}
```

**The question is, what should be put in that if statement above if you want this to happen:**

```
if (row 2 and row 1 are selected {

//Run this code.

}
```

UPDATE:

**Here's more code**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [_selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

} else {

    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [_selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];

}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

- (IBAction)doSomethingWithRowsSelected:(id)sender {

for (NSNumber *data in self.selectedIndexes) {
    NSLog(@"Row %ld is selected.", (long)[data integerValue] +1);

}

}
```

Comment: Rather than storing selections in an array, I suggest you use an `NSMutableIndexSet` then it is trivial to check if the two indexes you are interested in are selected

Comment: Is there a way with what I have?

Comment: @Paulw11 Added more code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use an array, as you do, an `NSMutableIndexSet` is a much better data structure for this task.  It allows you to check whether a given index is in the set without having to iterate through all of the objects.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableIndexSet *selectedRows;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.selectedRows containsIndex:row]) {
        [self.selectedRows removeIndex:row];
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else {
        [self.selectedRows addIndex:indexPath.row];
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];      
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Now you can easily check if any two rows are selected:

```
- (IBAction)doSomethingWithRowsSelected:(id)sender {
    if ([self.selectedRows containsIndex:1] && [self.selectedRows containsIndex:2]) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to set the accessory type in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based on `[self.selectedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]` otherwise your checkmarks will be wrong when you scroll.

Comment: I didn't show it, but you need to say `self.selectedRows  = [NSMutableIndexSet new];` somewhere like `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Oh sorry, got it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I will do,

1st, get the array of selected rows by using [indexPathsForSelectedRows](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows),

2nd, iterate the array to check if if indexPath.row is 1 or 2.

3rd, if your if statement's condition is true, then do ...

Comment: Is there a way with what I have?

Comment: @спасибо, do you think you could save the NSIndexPath in your `_selectedIndexes `? This could help a lot.